# Using large numbers in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field called `size` which is a `BIGINT` storing the number of bytes in a file. To get a file that is larger than `1GB` I am currently doing:

```
size > (1024*1024*1024)
```

But this looks a bit hairy. Is there another way to write this that makes it more clear that the result of `1024*1024*1024` is 1GiB?

Additionally is the exponent operator built into mysql? I've used

```
select power(2, 30)
```

But I was wondering if there was a shortform to do that directly in the query, such as `2^30`.

Comment: @ysth thanks, do you know other ways to display exponents in mysql?

Comment: The shortform is Pow(). It saves two whole characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the bitwise xor operator.

Either `POW(2,30)` or `POWER(2,30)` (or `POWER(1024,3)`) will work; I believe of the two `POWER` is the more standard.  There is no typographic operator for exponentiation.

I would just leave it as `1024*1024*1024`; to me that provides the best readability (and makes it clear it is 1 GiB, not 1 GB).